# AngularJS: Link with hash gets urlencoded

Tags: angularjs

I have a link like `http://localhost:8000/#?4047=27.20#4047`

If I paste it in and reload the page, everything works fine.

If I make a link like

```
<a href="{{ location.$$absUrl }}" target="_blank">same</a>
```

it works fine.

If I paste the link into my email or notes software, the link looks fine. But, when I click it, it gets urlencoded and fails with

```
http://localhost:8000/#?4047=27.20%234047
```

So, `$location.hash()` is empty.

I'm mostly working with chrome. Safari is similar but slightly worse. I paste in `http://localhost/#/?9189=668.00&7010=128.00#7010,9189` and it gets changed to `http://localhost/#/?9189=668.00&7010=128.00%237010,9189` and my app breaks.

Firefox seems to not encode the # and handle it just how I wanted. hrm.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to put this somewhere in the configuration, maybe. But, for my purposes, I can just "correct" the url, if needed, early on in a controller.

```
// aint nobody got time fo dat
$location.url($location.url().replace('%23', '#'));
```